# how to fast convert bootstrap button into png image file?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, png, converters

that I would like to say, there is a good (or maybe not) bootstrap framework that can generate buttons with simple code.
I really like how these buttons look, and I want to use them in another software, but for this I need them in PNG format.

Why is not satisfied with the option "manually" - the buttons need a lot and not always needed, but when needed - they need fast, do not really want to spend a lot of time creating buttons ...
Current process:

1. Open page (for example https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-button-generator.hhp) to set the necessary parameters (button name, size, type, color, icon ...)
2. Copy the whole screen to the buffer
3. Insert a screenshot from the buffer into an image editor
4. Make necessary cropping of this picture, leave only the image of the button itself
5. Save the result in png format
6. Use the image in your application.

That I would like to receive:

1. Open (no difference - internet page, any software, etc...)
2. Specify the required parameters (button text, size, color, icon)
3. Press the button - save to PNG, without loss of quality.
4. Use the image in your application

Maybe someone already solved a similar problem and translated it into a semi-automatic mode, share the implementation.
I use Win10 at workstation

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to manually crop them by Snipping Tool. This works great if you have just a few buttons.

But if you want to take them automatically, I think you can use an python/opencv script to idendify buttons, crop and save them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solution found - ShareX (https://getsharex.com/) software with 1 hotkey (ctrl + printscreen) - open crop dialog with zoom, after crop - makes the png-file automatic